# How to create a unique index using grails and mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, grails, gorm-mongodb

```java
class Country{
    String id
    String code
    Set<State> states
    static embedded = ['states']
}
class State{
    String id
    String code
}
```

I'm trying to set an unique index (Or gorm constraint validation) to country code  + state code

These doesn't work:

- code unique: true in constraints
- code index: true, indexAttributes: [unique: true]

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class State{
    String id
    String code
    static belongsTo = [country: Country]
    static constraints = {
        code( unique: ['country'])
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, if I add the belongsTo with the named field (static belongsTo = [country: Country]), grails crash with an infinite loop...